# Groupby using loops in python

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have ten dataframes with same column names 'Name' and 'data' respectively.

Using groupby and aggregation for all the dataset I am able to get the desired output but it is a lot of effort for ten dataset's and the margin of error increases because I need to maintain these dataset's separate.
examples and codes provided below.

```
Df1:

Name data
Foo  Product
Foo  Misc
Bar  Product
Bar  Item

Df2:

Name data
Foo  Misc
Foo  Product
Bar  Product
Bar  Item

Desired output:
Df1:

Name data
Foo  Product,Misc
Bar  Product,Item

Df2:

Name data
Foo  Misc, Product
Bar  Product,Item
```

Currently I am using the below code to achieve this task

```
Group1= Df1.groupby('Name')['data'].agg(['data',','.join)]).reset_index()

Group2 = Df2.groupby('Name')['data'].agg(['data',','.join)]).reset_index()
```

Have tried the below but did not work

```
Group = [Df1,Df2]

for df in Group:
     df.groupby('Name')['data'].agg(['data',','.join)]).reset_index()

Also based on some suggestions tried the below
Group = [Df1,Df2]

for df in Group:
   df =  df.groupby('Name')['data'].agg(['data',','.join)]).reset_index()

Both did not produce any result no error on code but it's giving me the file without any changes.
```

Comment: Do you want the new data store in memory somewhere or print them out?

Comment: I want it assigned to Df1 and Df2 respectively

Comment: then shouldn't you do assignment, e.g. `for df in Group: df = df.groupby['Name']...`?

Comment: is `Name` Col the same in both DataFrame?

Comment: @ansev yes it is

Comment: @Quang Hoang the problem is the code I have made is based on the knowledge I have which is not much so I did not want to ask a question without trying it at all

Comment: is  data the name of the other column in both dataframe?

Comment: So all ten dataframes have Name and Data column

Comment: @Quang Hoang I just tried what you suggested it did not work

Comment: Use df.groupby('Name')['Data'].apply(list)

Comment: @Pygirl it does not work thanks for trying :)

Comment: @ragethewolf: The problem is you are not able to modify the original dataframe right? My answer was not for that. Trying to provide you the solution for that also.

Comment: What does _it did not work_ and _it does not work_ mean? Debugging through comments like this is insane, please share a proper [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion is to use a dictionary.

```
dd = {'Df1':Df1,
      'Df2':Df2}


for k, v in dd.items():
    dd[k] = v.groupby('Name').agg(list)

dd
```

Output:

```
{'Df1':                  Data
 Name                 
 Bar   [Product, Item]
 Foo   [Product, Misc], 
 'Df2':                  Data
 Name                 
 Bar   [Product, Item]
 Foo   [Misc, Product]}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Scott but I need to extract the data into Excel.

Comment: @ragethewolf date?  You can still access the dataframes using dd['Df1'] and dd['Df2'].

Comment: Oh din know that will try this out too. Thanks  Scott

Comment: Thanks.for this Scott I used this for my programme

Answer (score 1):

```
Df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Foo','Foo','Bar','Bar'],
                   'Data':['Product','Misc', 'Product', 'Item'],
                   })

Df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Foo','Foo','Bar','Bar'],
                   'Data':['Misc', 'Product', 'Product', 'Item'],
                   })
```

**Solution**

```
fields=[f'Df{i}' for i in range(1,3)]
dfsout=[Df1, Df2]
variables = locals()
for d,name in zip(dfsout,fields):
    variables["{0}".format(name)]=pd.DataFrame(d.groupby('Name')['Data'].apply(list)).reset_index(level=0)
```

**Df1:**

```
    Name    Data
0   Foo Product
1   Foo Misc
2   Bar Product
3   Bar Item
```

**Df2:**

```
Name    Data
0   Foo Misc
1   Foo Product
2   Bar Product
3   Bar Item
```

***After Implementing the solution part:***

**Df1:**

```
     Data
Name    
Bar [Product, Item]
Foo [Product, Misc]
```

**Df2:**

```
     Data
Name    
Bar [Product, Item]
Foo [Misc, Product]
```

Comment: This is perfect just one help required when I am exporting data to xlsx my Name column is disappearing

Comment: Add  .reset_index(level=0) to ---> variables["{0}".format(name)]=pd.DataFrame(d.groupby('Name')['Data'].apply(list))

Comment: I have Edited my answer. actually your column name became index. That's why you were not getting name while importing I changed Name back from index to a column by using reset_index

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [df1,df2]
for df in a:
    tmp = df.groupby(['Name'])['data'].apply(','.join).reset_index()
    df = df.append(tmp,ignore_index = True)
```

this will not change df1 and df2, 
but a[0] and a[1] will be updated, so if you don't mind accessing threw the list, you have there the updated tables